Unable to connect to internet in Kali Linux 2024.2 after the error "Your Network is probably not using the DHCP protocol."
I can't connect to my internet in Kali Linux. I installed Kali on a Virtual Machine using Oracle VM VirtualBox.

During the installation I encountered the error:

"Your Network is probably not using the DHCP protocol. Alternatively, the DHCP server may be slow or some network hardware is not working properly."

Windows version:

Windows 11 Pro
Version 23H2

ifconfig output:
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 08:00:27:19:55:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 64  bytes 4720 (4.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 64  bytes 4720 (4.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


Have you installed the driver for the adapter within the guest os? [Edit] your question to include the necessary to diagnose your issue. One critical piece of information is the output of ifconfig

Is there a reason you are not using WSL? It is much easier to use and configure.

Hi, I'm new to virtualbox and VMs, how do I know if the drivers are installed, and how to install them?

I haven't tried it, by the way the ifconfig output will be on the post, I'm editing it. I know what it is but i prefer to use virtualbox

@Ramhound do you know how to fix it?

Based on ifconfig your VM doesn’t have an Ethernet adapter. Which explains the DHCP error. Kali isn’t meant for Linux beginners and I simply don’t have enough information to further diagnose the problem

@Ramhound Thanks, do you know anyonr i could refer to?

I suggest either using Kali within WSL or using a different Linux distribution within a VM.

Alright, thank you!
